# arm-eabi-addr2line don't show line number

Tags: c++, android, c

I am running the arm-eabi-addr2line for my Android project, my command is

```
/Applications/android-sdk-mac_86/android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-eabi-addr2line -C -f -e {my so file} {address}
```

and found that it always only return the function name but don't show line number, e.g,

```
XXX::XXX::XXX()
??:0
```

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have debugging symbols in your .so? You should also disable optimization (-O0) and inline functions (-fno-inline)

Comment: thanks ,but how to add debugging symbols to .so? and what is your meaning of (-O0) and (-fno-inline)

Comment: In Application.mk just add `APP_OPTIM := debug` and the NDK makefiles will adjust it for you